# How to tell if a mixed array contains string elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

**Practice Problem I am working on:**

> Write a function called "findShortestWordAmongMixedElements".
>
> Given an `array`, `findShortestWordAmongMixedElements` returns the shortest string within the given array.
>
> Notes:
>   * If there are ties, it should return the first element to appear in the given array.
>   * Expect the given array to have values other than strings.
>   * If the given array is empty, it should return an empty string.
>   *** If the given array contains no strings, it should return an empty string.**

This is currently what I have coded:

```
function findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(array) {
  if (array.length === 0)) {
    return '';
  }
  var result = array.filter(function (value) {
    return typeof value === 'string';
  });
  var shortest = result.reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a.length <= b.length ? a : b;
  });
  return shortest;
}

var newArr = [ 4, 'two','one', 2, 'three'];

findShortestWordAmongMixedElements(newArr);
//returns 'two'
```

Everything works but I can't figure out how to pass the "if given array contains no strings" test. I was thinking of adding some kind of `!array.includes(string??)` to the `if` statement but am not sure how to go about it.

Any hints? or even smarter way to write this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with *reduce* and initial value like *null* (or any specific non-string value). Look for the shortest string and if there are no strings, *reduce* will return the initial value. So if that is returned, return an empty string instead.

```js
function getShortest(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(acc, value) {
    if (typeof value == 'string') {
      if (acc === null || value.length < acc.length) {
        acc = value;
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, null) || '';
}

var test0 = [ 4, 'two','one', 2, 'three']; // Has strings
var test1 = [ 4, {},[], 2, new Date()];    // No strings
var test2 = [];                            // Empty
var test3 = [ 4, 'two','', 2, 'three']; // Has strings, shortest empty

console.log('test0: "' + getShortest(test0) + '"'); // "two"
console.log('test1: "' + getShortest(test1) + '"'); // no strings
console.log('test2: "' + getShortest(test2) + '"'); // empty
console.log('test3: "' + getShortest(test3) + '"'); // ""
```

This should be more efficient than *filter* with *reduce* as it only goes over the array once.

Answer (score 4):

> *"Everything works but I can't figure out how to pass the "if given array contains no strings" test."*

You are already using `.filter()` to get an array of just the strings. If that `result` array is empty then there were no strings. (I'm assuming you don't need me to show code for this, because you already have code that tests if an array is empty.)